# Execute a script before CMD

Tags: docker, environment-variables

As per [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):
There can only be one CMD instruction in a Dockerfile. If you list more than one CMD then only the last CMD will take effect.

I wish to execute a simple bash script(which processes docker environment variable) before the CMD command(which is init in my case).

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile

Comment: Put your bash script as `CMD` in `Dockerfile` and move the current command you have in `CMD` into the bash script, as the last command it runs.

Comment: @axiac I tried it..it didn't helped. CMD is init

Answer (score 56, accepted):

### Use a custom entrypoint

Make a custom entrypoint which does what you want, and then exec's your CMD at the end.

> **NOTE**: if your image already defines a custom entrypoint, you may need to extend it rather than replace it, or you may change behavior you need.

**entrypoint.sh**:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

## Do whatever you need with env vars here ...

# Hand off to the CMD
exec "$@"
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 755 /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Docker will run your entrypoint, using CMD as arguments. If your CMD is `init`, then:

```
/entrypoint.sh init
```

The `exec` at the end of the entrypoint script takes care of handing off to CMD when the entrypoint is done with what it needed to do.

### Why this works

The use of ENTRYPOINT and CMD frequently confuses people new to Docker. In comments, you expressed confusion about it. Here is how it works and why.

The ENTRYPOINT is the initial thing run inside the container. It takes the CMD as an argument list. Therefore, in this example, what is run in the container is this argument list:

```
# ENTRYPOINT = /entrypoint.sh
# CMD        = init
["/entrypoint.sh", "init"]

# or shown in a simpler form:
/entrypoint.sh init
```

It is not required that an image have an ENTRYPOINT. If you don't define one, Docker has a default: `/bin/sh -c`.

So with your original situation, no ENTRYPOINT, and using a CMD of `init`, Docker would have run this:

```
/bin/sh -c 'init'
^--------^  ^--^
    |         \------- CMD
    \--------------- ENTRYPOINT
```

In the beginning, Docker offered only CMD, and `/bin/sh -c` was hard-coded as the ENTRYPOINT (you could not change it). At some point along the way, people had use cases where they had to do more custom things, and Docker exposed ENTRYPOINT so you could change it to anything you want.

In the example I show above, the ENTRYPOINT is replaced with a custom script. (Though it is still ultimately being run by `sh`, because it starts with `#!/bin/sh`.)

That ENTRYPOINT takes the CMD as is argument. At the end of the entrypoint.sh script is `exec "$@"`. Since `$@` expands to the list of arguments given to the script, this is turned into

```sh
exec "init"
```

And therefore, when the script is finished, it goes away and is replaced by `init` as PID 1. (That's what `exec` does - it *replaces* the current process with a different command.)

### How to include CMD

In the comments, you asked about adding CMD in the Dockerfile. Yes, you can do that.

**Dockerfile**:

```
CMD ["init"]
```

Or if there is more to your command, e.g. arguments like `init -a -b`, would look like this:

```
CMD ["init", "-a", "-b"]
```

Comment: Thanks! - one question - Can I have CMD as part of Dockerfile (instead of specifying as argument). like..
`ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]                                                                             CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34245657/124330 - But this answer confuses me..am a newbie to Docker. Here ENTRYPOINT is ping and CMD is localhost..so it is like ping localhost..but in my case it will look like /entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/init - which does not make sense for me - how come init can be argument to entrypoint.sh script ?

Comment: @kumar I updated the answer with an explanation of ENTRYPOINT and CMD. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment.  I'm having trouble trying to get this to work.  When running 'docker logs -f <container>', it saying "/bin/sh: [startup.sh]: command not found."   NOTE: my script is called startup.sh.  Also i'm building ontop of another container that has this in its Dockerfile: CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"].  Here's basically what's in my Dockerfile:  WORKDIR /
COPY startup.sh /
RUN chmod 755 /startup.sh
ENTRYPOINT ['/startup.sh']

Comment: @jerseybean If you have a question you should post it as a question, and include the Dockerfile, contents of startup.sh, in that question

Comment: I have done this: `ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh", "/usr/bin/java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/app/resources/LINUX/${LOG4J_FILE} -Dpa.config=/app/resources/LINUX/${CONFIG_FILE} -jar /app/app.jar"]` and in entrypoint file end: `exec "$@"` But docker is unable to launch the container, it exits, container log shows: `/app/entrypoint.sh: line 7: /usr/bin/java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/app/resources/LINUX/${LOG4J_FILE} -Dpa.config=/app/resources/LINUX/${CONFIG_FILE} -jar /app/app.jar: No such file or directory` - what does this mean? what is wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Dan's answer was correct, but I found it rather confusing to implement. For those in the same situation, here are code examples of how I implemented his explanation of the use of ENTRYPOINT instead of CMD.

Here are the last few lines in my Dockerfile:

```
#change directory where the mergeandlaunch script is located.
WORKDIR /home/connextcms
ENTRYPOINT ["./mergeandlaunch", "node", "keystone.js"]
```

Here are the contents of the mergeandlaunch bash shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#This script should be edited to execute any merge scripts needed to
#merge plugins and theme files before starting ConnextCMS/KeystoneJS.

echo Running mergeandlaunch script

#Execute merge scripts. Put in path to each merge script you want to run here.
cd ~/theme/rtb4/
./merge-plugin

#Launch KeystoneJS and ConnextCMS
cd ~/myCMS

exec "$@"
```

Here is how the code gets executed:

1. The ENTRYPOINT command kicks off the `mergeandlaunch` shell script
2. The two arguments 'node' and 'keystone.js' are passed along to the shell script.
3. At the end of the script, the arguments are passed on to the `exec` command.
4. The exec command then launched my node program the same way the Docker command CMD would do.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dan for his answer.

Although I found I had to do something like this within the Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /
COPY startup.sh /
RUN chmod 755 /startup.sh
ENTRYPOINT sh /startup.sh /usr/sbin/init
```

NOTE: I named the script startup.sh as opposed to entrypoint.sh

The key here was that I needed to provide 'sh' otherwise I kept getting "no such file..." errors coming out of 'docker logs -f container_name'.

See:
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3876