# Inherit all env variables using Apache

Tags: apache, kubernetes, httpd.conf, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod

I see these docs:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_env.html

I am looking to inherit/pass all env vars from the host to apache so that I can access them in CGI scripts. Right now the cgi-scripts will log the env vars like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
env | sort | while read line; echo "$line <br>"; done
```

but when the cgi script runs that, it only logs env vars that pertain to apache/httpd, no env vars which are from the outer environment are logged, but why?

So I think am looking to do something like:

```
PassEnv *
```

but that's just a guess, anyone know something that might pass all env variables?

To be specific we are using Kubernetes/(AWS EKS), here is our configuration for replicas/pods:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: apache-spike
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: apache-spike
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: apache-spike
        image: 913617820371.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/interos_apache:latest
        ports:
        - name: http-port
          containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
          - name: DEMO_GREETING
            value: "Hello from the environment"
          - name: DEMO_FAREWELL
            value: "demo farewell env var"
```

and when we *describe* one of the pods, we see:

```
Containers:
  apache-spike:
    Container ID:   docker://6727d6eafe2a6d229c58875c8cf2c2e9a0cff517dbe67600f965fe19eee000c1
    Image:          9136xxxx0371.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/interos_apache:latest
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://9136xxxx0371.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/interos_apache@sha256:74f6cab7ef4e1b93123c6e61c7cbdbe5960b736f7e26e075ea5031fb838437be
    Port:           8080/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 07 May 2019 17:12:07 -0700
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      DEMO_GREETING:  Hello from the environment
      DEMO_FAREWELL:  demo farewell env var
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-jhvnp (ro)
```

so the environment variables are there, at least.

When I run this command on a pod:

```
kubectl exec apache-spike-579598949b-5bjjs -c apache-spike -- sh -c 'id && ps -e'
```

I get this:

```
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:04 httpd
    7 ?        00:00:00 httpd
    8 ?        00:00:11 httpd
    9 ?        00:00:09 httpd
   10 ?        00:00:09 httpd
   92 ?        00:00:13 httpd
  204 ?        00:00:00 sh
  211 ?        00:00:00 ps
```

Comment: in other words, I am running apache in a Docker container....if I run `docker run -e FOO=bar <image>`, I want to be able to echo $FOO using a cgi script, etc.

Comment: Can you share the UIDs for the running container and the apache proccess? Run the follow command and share the result `kubectl exec ${POD_NAME} -c apache-spike -- sh -c 'id && ps -e'`

Comment: for sure I just updated the OP with that information for a single pod

Comment: my guess is that apache doesn't inherit env variables or something when it runs cgi-scripts

Answer (score 0):

`PassEnv` doesn't take wildcards, so each environment variable will have to be listed by name. You can automate that using the [compgen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151120/119895) command.

In the Dockerfile:

```
# Configure an ENTRYPOINT to run setup commands prior to CMD.
# See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42858351/2932891
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 755 /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

# Run Apache however you like.
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

In the `entrypoint.sh` script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Append a PassEnv directive to the root .htaccess file, listing all exported
# shell variables, in order to expose them to CGI scripts via Apache.
# See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151120/119895
htaccess=/your_project/webroot/.htaccess
printf "\n# Expose environment variables to scripts.\nPassEnv" >> $htaccess
compgen -e | while read name ; do
    printf " $name" >> $htaccess
done
printf "\n" >> $htaccess

# Hand off to the CMD defined in Dockerfile.
exec "$@"
```

If the `.htaccess` approach isn't good for you then you could write this somewhere else on your filesystem and `Include` it in an Apache VirtualHost configuration.

Comment: Note that this isn't limited to the variables you've set in your Kubernetes manifests; you'll get a variety of mundane shell variables passed through as well. But due to the search-based nature of `compgen` you do have some filtering capabilities available, if you need them.

Comment: If you're using PHP-FPM rather than mod_php, you may also need to set "clear_env = no" in the configuration for your pool workers.