# Docker exec command in entrypoint script fails

Tags: shell, docker, environment-variables, docker-entrypoint

Following the suggestion on [Execute a script before CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857897/execute-a-script-before-cmd/44977960#44977960) (I needed to clear out a temp dir before a container is re-launched, to fix a bug), I modified my docker file from using a CMD, to entrypoint as follows:

`ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh", "/usr/bin/java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/app/resources/LINUX/${LOG4J_FILE} -Dpa.config=/app/resources/LINUX/${CONFIG_FILE} -jar /app/app.jar"]`

and in entrypoint file end after the rm -rf command:

`exec "$@"`

But docker is unable to launch the container, it exits, container log shows:

`+ exec '/usr/bin/java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/app/resources/LINUX/${LOG4J_FILE} -Dpa.config=/app/resources/LINUX/${CONFIG_FILE} -jar /app/app.jar'`
`/app/entrypoint.sh: line 7: /usr/bin/java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/app/resources/LINUX/${LOG4J_FILE} -Dpa.config=/app/resources/LINUX/${CONFIG_FILE} -jar /app/app.jar: No such file or directory` - what does this mean? what is wrong?

Comment: Does `/usr/bin/java` exist in your image?

Comment: It has to, the image did not change, I only changed the code to run that command last via entrypoint script instead of `CMD`, so I can run `rm -rf` command before... But anyway I just logged into a container overriding the entrypoint script, and verified manually - the file is there: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Dec 14 18:14 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java` which points at `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 73 Dec 14 18:14 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.el7_7.x86_64/jre/bin/java`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break the JSON-array-format command line into separate words.  Since you’ve explicitly told Docker that the “command” part of this is a single word, it’s looking for a binary file in `/usr/bin` named `java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=...`, with the spaces and options and all as part of the filename, and not finding it.

You typically don’t want to embed the command you want to run in `ENTRYPOINT`, especially if you’re using this wrapper layout.  Make `ENTRYPOINT` just be the name of the script ending in `exec "$@"`; it must use JSON-array syntax.  Make `CMD` be the actual command you want to run, in whichever syntax is more convenient.  (If you’re trying to expand environment variables, the shell-oriented syntax might be better.)

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD /usr/bin/java \
  -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/app/resources/LINUX/${LOG4J_FILE} \
  -Dpa.config=/app/resources/LINUX/${CONFIG_FILE} \
  -jar /app/app.jar
```

I’ve found this pattern to be sufficiently common and useful that I’d generally recommend using `ENTRYPOINT` only for this sort of wrapper script; prefer putting the command to start your application as `CMD`, even if you don’t have an entrypoint wrapper.

Comment: It worked, thanks! I still don't understand this though.. its not clearly documented feature, feels more like a hack.